# Correct way to "use" libraries in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm working through "Clojure in Action", and I have been instructed to create a file "in a folder named chapter08 within your source directory" and try to require it.

I created the following files (tried both - and _ delimited)

```
~/clojure-1.4.0$ ls src/chapter08/
date-operations-spec.clj    date_operations.clj
date-operations.clj     date_operations_spec.clj
```

I tried to require in the REPL using code from the book, but keep failing:

```
~/clojure-1.4.0$ java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> 
(ns chapter08.date-operations-spec
  (:use chapter08.date-operations)
  (:use clojure.test))
FileNotFoundException Could not locate chapter08/date_operations__init.class or chapter08/date_operations.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use leiningen which has become the ubiquitous tool for managing such things since Amit published that excellent book. I just spent longer writing this than the time required to setup leiningen.

then run lein new chapter8.
copy the file to chapter8/src/chapter8/
Run lein repl

Comment: Any suggestions on a more up-to-date introduction to Clojure that includes lein info?

Comment: Agreed. I started with cake, and eventually migrated to lein, which is an excellent tool.

Comment: The book is sufficiently current and I whole heartedly recommend it. Really once you find leiningen, the emacs starter kit (and install emacs24 not emacs23), and get used to paredit mode things are fairly well covered for the time being. Most of the books out there will likely outlive the current crop of build tools in terms of utility

Answer (score 1):

Using plain java to start clojure is a pain in the neck. For instance, your `java -cp ...` call will not put ./src on the classpath . Please just use [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen).